# Buttons on camera overlay not responding to touches

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, xib, camera-overlay

I've searched far and wide across the internet, but to no avail. Basically, I have a `viewController` that is presenting a `UIImagePickerController` every time it appears (in `viewWillAppear`). I'm using a custom `camera` overlay (`xib` file) for the `UIImagePickerController`. Everything is working fine, I can get the `camera` overlay to appear and I can see all of my `buttons` on the `camera` overlay, but none of the `buttons` are working/responding to any `touch events`. I've connected the `buttons` to the `viewController` using

```
-(IBAction)buttonName:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"This button doesn't work");  //to test the button
}
```

but for some reason I'm encountering this problem. Any thoughts?

Comment: I created the buttons in xib, then connected them by clicking/dragging to the view controller.

Comment: It might be possible that buttons are not on top of all views. Can you try to add them with code instead of nib and check?

Comment: Usually this symptom is caused by the buttons being outside the bounds of their superview. To check this, you can either give their superview a background color, or set its clipsToBounds property to YES (and see if the buttons disappear).

Comment: I set clipsToBounds to YES and they all disappeared, but I'm a little confused now because I'm not sure how that happens. Is it that I created the buttons outside the bounds in interface builder, or does it have to do with something else?

Comment: So I realize now that the buttons being outside the bounds of the superview is the problem and I tried setting the bounds programatically just to see what would happen and I can see part of the buttons, and they work. I don't know how to make sure that the bounds encompass the whole screen so that all the buttons are included though. Basically, how can I set the bounds to include the whole camera overlay?